# Search certain value in an array list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm supposed to build a member class including username and password in Microsoft visual studio C#. In my web page when a user try to log in , the the user name would be appear as label on the web page.

1. This is my member class

Code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System. Linq;
 using System.Web;
 public class Member
 {`enter code here`
    private string id;
    private string name;
    private string username;
    private string password;
    private int phone;
    private string email;
    private int postal;
    public Member(string id, string name, string username, string password,       int phone, string email, int postal)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
        this.postal = postal;
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return Password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }
    public int Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }
    public int Postal
    {
        get { return postal; }
        set { postal = value; }
    }


}
```

2. I inserted the value in global.asax

code:

```
List<Member> MemberList = new List<Member>();

        Member m1 = new Member("m1","U1" ,"name1", "password1", 123, "email 1", 1234);
        Member m2 = new Member("m2", "U2","name2", "password1", 456, "email 2", 2345);
        Member m3 = new Member("m3","U2", "name3", "password1", 789, "email 3", 3456);
        Member m4 = new Member("m4", "U2","name4", "password1", 987, "email 4",4567);
        Member m5 = new Member("m5","U2", "name5"," password1", 654, "email 5", 5678);
        MemberList.Add(m1);
        MemberList.Add(m2);
        MemberList.Add(m3);
        MemberList.Add(m4);
        MemberList.Add(m5);
        Application["members"] = Memberlist`*enter code here*`;
```

4.Then i try to authenticate the typed value with existing values in array list

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
            List<Member> MemberList = (List<Member>)Application["members"];


            string s = signintext.Text;
            foreach (Member m in MemberList)
            {
                if (s == m.Username)
                    Label1.Text = signintext.Text;

            }        

    }
```

5. After that i try to sign in with the correct username "name1" the error appear (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).Is the whole logic wrong or is there something i am missing?.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that like this. Use [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) instead.

Comment: I am supposed to use sql database on my second part of the assignment. That;s why I m doing like this.